# sp_AllNightLog - running on an existing SQL server

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I am trying to get sp_AllNightLog running on an existing server that had regular SQL log shipping (now removed) and Ola Hallengren's backup utility for nightly backups.

I have the procs and jobs configured, but they only take log backups, so it won't seed the secondary server.

I assume this is due to Ola's scripts having been run on the DBs before so they are not reverting to a full back up.  How can I force the full backup on first run?

Answer (score 3):

Great job on troubleshooting, and yes, you are correct. Ola Hallengren's backup scripts need a change as described in this Github issue for his scripts:

https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution/issues/12

Ola hasn't accepted the pull request yet (he's fairly new to Github), so if you want to use my fixed version with the new parameters I describe in that issue, here's my repo:

https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/sql-server-maintenance-solution

If all that sounds too scary - and I wouldn't blame you - then you'll need to seed the restores yourself manually for each new database.